# Titanium How to add 2 merge two Ti.Media.sound objects?

Tags: javascript, iphone, object, merge, titanium

```
//Assuming cricket.wav file has audio information of 5 secs.
var file1 = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'cricket.wav');
//Assuming mahamed.wav file has audio information of 25 secs.
var file2 = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'test.wav');
```

//How do i merge both file1 and file2 and create a file which should have audio information of  30 secs.?

```
var file = file1 + file2; // This is giving me an error.
```

I need file which will play file1 then followed by file2.

Comment: This should be a trick not a combination of two files. try to play files one after another and show the progress bar like that one file is continued after the other.

Comment: @muhammad I knew this trick but i have strange requirement like, on button click i need to get the duration and then i need to delete the audio from the current duration to end of the file. How do we do this?

Comment: you mean once the file1 is played completely, the progress bar will again start from 0 and then will play file2?

Comment: @muhammad No I need a single file which has the audio of both the files. And while playing that single file on button click i shud be able delete the sound information from the current playing duration to end.

Comment: Again... you are playing both the files one after and another. why are you deleting the file? I don't know the merge of files. just tell you that you should play both files one by one and manage the progress bar accordingly,

Answer (score 0):

You have a few choices. Learn Objective C and drop Titanium since it can't do what you are asking or upload your files to a server somewhere combine them and then download the single combined file. The other is what Muhammad is saying where you create your own custom timers and use the `duration` and `looping` values to make it play out correctly. Personally I would go with the server method.